# Java webservice in tomcat using axis

Tags: java, service, axis

I would like to ask a few questions to make sure that I understand things.

When creating a web service using tomcat and axis, I create an interface defining the methods that I am going to expose. so far so good. I have a couple more classes as well. I compile my classes (.class files no jars) an store them in WEB-INF\classes ..right??  I hardcode my deploy.wsdd file and by using Admin or AdminClient (axis helper classes) I integrate the deploy.wsdd to the server-config.wsdd file.

everything is working fine.

Questions:

1. Is it ok to have classes (.class files) in WEB-INF\classes directory?? should i create a jar or war file and store it somewhere???
2. I have tried using java2wsdl (giving it the interface.class as input) to produce a wsdl file and then wsdl2java. I did that in order to generate deploy.wsdd file and then integrate it in server-config.wsdd file. The deploy.wsdd file generated is not correct and my service is not working properly. What am i missing here?? is there a different way to generate the deploy.wsdd file?????

Help???

Thanx in advance.
Theo

Answer (score 0):

1. It's perfectly okay to have .class files in WEB-INF/classes, as long as they're in packages.  Tomcat doesn't like using the default package.
2. I'm not sure, because I'm not an Axis fan.  This is all a lot easier with Spring "contract first" web services.  You aren't tied to Axis if you use it (but you are tied to Spring).